# nth derivative in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to find the 3rd derivative of eq. x^5+4x^4+3x^2+5 using sympy.

My code is:

```
x = symbols(‘x’)
y = parse_expr(exp)
z = diff(y,x,n)
print(z)
```

It gives answer in this form 12*x*(5*x+8) instead of 60*x**2+96x

Comment: The example code is not valid python.

Comment: in your code `exp` and `n` are not defined. The return has a syntax typo (capital R) and you cannot return if you are not inside a function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
exp = x**5 + 4*x**4 + 3*x**2 + 5

y = diff(exp,x,3)
print("y = ", y)

z = y.expand()
print("z = ", z)
```

This gives:

```
y =  12*x*(5*x + 8)
z =  60*x**2 + 96*x
```